# Jquery function to check if SRCset of image finish load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to modify a a function that change a image via SRCset.
Right now i can check if the srcset attribute has changed. That's ok.
But on slow connections, the srcset attribute changes and after a few seconds the image it self change on browser view.

Is there a way to check if the image display really finish loading and not only the img attribute?

I tried MutationObserver, .load(), .onLoad() etc

Sorry if that is not clear or the question is just dumb

Thanks

Edit:

The soluction at the end was something like this:

```
var previewIMG = jQuery(this).find('.product-grid-image img');
var swatchImgSRC = jQuery(this).attr("data-product-sku");


previewIMG.one("load", function(){
  LoadingDiv.removeClass('active-loading');
}).attr("srcset", swatchImgSRC);
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Hi @MattOestreich.
Bilel was able to help me out with the answers to my question. The only thing that worked so far was the Jquery One. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think jQuery [One](https://api.jquery.com/one/) can help you here Whether with src or srcset!

```js
var newsrc="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d1/Wikipedia-logo-v2-fr.svg/1200px-Wikipedia-logo-v2-fr.svg.png";
$("img").click(function() {
    $("img").one("load", function() {
        $("#info").append("loaded!");
    }).attr("src", newsrc);
});
```

```html
  <h1 id="info"></h1>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://srcset.salcode.com/images/2000x1000.png" style="width:300px;">
```

Whatever you like to do and being sure the image is loaded, you can call near the append() example here.

Comment: Hi @Bilel
Your suggested solution works perfectly for me. The only thing that work so far.

Thank you so much

Comment: When satisfied, you can set it as an accepted answer ;) You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

onLoad() should works:

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9a/Big_Mac_hamburger.jpg/1024px-Big_Mac_hamburger.jpg" id="myImg" alt="mmmm bigmac"/>

const img = document.getElementById('myImg');
img.onload = e => {
      console.log('img loaded !');
}
```

will only print 'img loaded' when it is completely loaded.

Comment: Hi @r-sede. Thank you for your answer.
As I mention the question I already tried the onLoad to check the real load of the srcSET of the image. Already fixed with jQuery One :)